# How can I bulk change sprites for my game object?

Tags: sdl2, component-based, gameobject, asset-management

I'm using an asset pack that has 4 characters and I want the player to rotate between them whenever they respawn or in other words I wanna be able to bulk change an objects sprites. I've been learning about the component-based entity system architecture so that's what I'm using for my project I have a `PlayerGraphics` component and the idea for it is to store/handle all the assets related to the player so that when I add it to a player object the object will have those assets to work with.

The issue is once the object is created (even before it's created) I don't really have a way to set which assets I want to use.

```
    PlayerGraphics(Graphics& graphics, AssetManager& assetManager) : graphics(graphics), assetManager(assetManager) {
        CharacterAssets ninjaFrog;
        ninjaFrog.doubleJump = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Double Jump (32x32).png"); // 6 frames
        ninjaFrog.fall = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Fall (32x32).png"); // 1 frame
        ninjaFrog.hit = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Hit (32x32).png"); // 7 frames
        ninjaFrog.idle = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Idle (32x32).png"); // 11 frames
        ninjaFrog.jump = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Jump (32x32).png"); // 1 frames
        ninjaFrog.run = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Run (32x32).png"); // 12 frames
        ninjaFrog.wallJump = assetManager.loadAsset("Source/Assets/characters/Ninja Frog/Wall Jump (32x32).png"); // 5 frames
        // This chunk of code is repeated 3 more times for Mask Dude, Virtual Guy, and Pink Man

        sprite.addAnimation("idle", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.idle), 11, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("run", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.run), 12, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("fall", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.fall), 1, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("jump", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.jump), 1, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("doubleJump", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.doubleJump), 6, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("wallJump", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.wallJump), 5, 32, 32, 50.0f);
        sprite.addAnimation("hit", assetManager.getAsset(ninjaFrog.hit), 7, 32, 32, 50.0f);

        sprite.playAnimation("idle");
    }
```

P.S: I'm using SDL2